Check if parameter pack contains a std::span<U>
I am iterating over an argument sequence at compile-time, and I want to check if one of the arguments may be a span. If so, I will do span-things.
    template<typename... Args, std::size_t... Indices>
    inline auto SomeClass::resolve_args(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) const
    {
        std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...> retval;
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t f = 0;
        ([&] {
            if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<Args>) {
                std::get<Indices>(retval) = sysarg<Args>(i++);
            }
            else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<Args>)
                std::get<Indices>(retval) = sysarg<Args>(f++);
            else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Args, std::basic_string_view<char>>) {
                std::get<Indices>(retval) = sysarg<Args>(i); i+= 2;
            }
            else if constexpr (is_stdstring<Args>::value)
                std::get<Indices>(retval) = sysarg<Args>(i++);
            else if constexpr (std::is_standard_layout_v<remove_cvref<Args>> && std::is_trivial_v<remove_cvref<Args>>)
                std::get<Indices>(retval) = sysarg<Args>(i++);
            else
                static_assert(always_false<Args>, "Unknown type");
        }(), ...);
        return retval;
    }

Somewhere in there I need to check if Args is a Span. Is that possible?
My problem so far is that my attempts at an if constexpr branch makes other type-combinations fail. So, I am posting the whole function (with minor modifications). You can implement sysarg as a do-nothing function.
Ideally, the spans subtype would be trivial and standard_layout, but I can handle the details. I just need to figure out how to proceed!

" I need to check if Args is a Span..." That is not possible as Args is a parameter pack.  You cannot compare a parameter pack with a class-type just as we cannot compare 1kg with 1km. Maybe you meant that you want to check if one of the argument of/inside Args is std::span<T>  as written at the beginning of your post.

Just a FYI, this function is working as intended. You are confusing Args outside of the lambda fold, with the one inside.

fwiw, the accepted answer in the duplicate wont work for std::span.

In this case I would not use if constexpr, but leverage overload resolution. Anyway what should happen when there is std::span? What does it mean do span-things?

#include <span>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_span : std::false_type{};
template <typename T>
struct is_span<std::span<T>> : std::true_type{};
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_span_v = is_span<T>::value;

int main() {
    static_assert(is_span_v<std::span<int>>);
    static_assert(!is_span_v<int>);
}

Edit:
The above only works for spans with dynamic extent. To make it work on all spans change the is_span specialization to this:
template <typename T, std::size_t Extent>
struct is_span<std::span<T, Extent>> : std::true_type{};

live example

Isn't std::span<int, 6> span?

@康桓瑋 : Correct. This only matches std::dynamic_extent spans.

@康桓瑋 Yeah, I was a bit to quick to answer. Updated it.
